# Can't get full HTML from facebook page

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm trying to get HTML from facebook about/ page. When I'm making request I get only part of a page without any usefull data.
eg. website -> https://www.gatesnotes.com/ from https://web.facebook.com/BillGates/about/

```
import request from 'request';

const url = 'https://web.facebook.com/BillGates/about/';

let urlsArray = await new Promise(
            function (resolve, reject) {
              request(url, function (error, res, body) {
                if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
                  resolve(body);
                } else {
                  reject(error);
                }
              });
          })
          .then(
            function (res) {
              let validateUrls = validateUrl(res);
              return validateUrls;
            },
            function (reason) {
              console.error('Something went wrong', reason);
              return reason;
         });
```

How can I wait for whole page to be load before requesting ?

Comment: would need to render the asynchronous data in a headless browser. Open the same page in your browser and do *'view source'* and won't see near as much as in live html inspection in browser dev tools

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. Use the API.

Comment: @charlietfl Oh you are right ! so when I will use something with headless browser I will be able to do it ? ;)

Comment: agree with @WizKid though...they will catch on pretty quickly and block you

Comment: We are better than that.